# How to make the html pattern attribute validate in angular

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I'm trying to set a pattern validator in my angular form. No matter how I put it in, it doesn't validate the pattern. I created a simple reproducible example. the [(ngModel)]="".. has to remain. I thaught if I used simple html this would work, but it doesn't. In this example I followed the below link and inserted in my exisiting angular code. It states clearly that 'pattern' gets validated on form submission.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

The problem with using thing like formbuilder, which I can find online tutorials regarding validating in Angular, is that it witholds me from using the [(ngModel)]. In need to be able to implement it in my exisiting form.

app.component.html

```
<h1>form</h1>


<form role="form" (submit)="testpattern()" #testForm="ngForm">

  <input required type="text" name="riziv" [pattern]="[0-9]" [(ngModel)]="inputform.riziv">
  <button type="submit" (onclick)="testpattern()">test pattern</button>


</form>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'testout';
  inputform={riziv:''};




  constructor(
  ) { }

  testpattern(): void {
    console.log(this.inputform.riziv);
  }


}
```

No matter what I put in, nothing gets validated by the pattern. The console just logs whatever I put in. How do I make this validate when using [(ngModel)]?

Comment: If you have a problem with regex, please explain what you expect to match.

Comment: Wiktor, I clearified the question, can you help now please? My regex is fine(actual is different),but the form just doesn't validate against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern works just fine. It is the submit button that is configured wrong. When I added

> [disabled]="adduserForm.form.invalid"

the button only gets abled when the pattern is formed correctly.